# Topology - Separation Axioms

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A quick question that will help better clarify the separation axioms:

On a set with three elements, there are nine inequivalent topologies (listed below). Which of these topologies are $T_{0}$, $T_{1}$, $T_{2}$, $T_{3}$ (regular, or not), and $T_{4}$ (normal, or not)?

Let $X=\{a, b, c\}$ be a set with 3 elements.

1. {$\emptyset$, {a, b, c}}
2. {$\emptyset$, {c}, {a, b, c}}
3. {$\emptyset$, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}
4. {$\emptyset$,{c}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}
5. {$\emptyset$, {c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}
6. {$\emptyset$, {c}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}
7. {$\emptyset$, {a}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}
8. {$\emptyset$, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}
9. {$\emptyset$, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}}

So, I already know that $T_{2}$ implies $T_{1}$, which implies $T_{0}$. Also, that $T_{3}$  and $T_{4}$ do not ensure the previous three separation axioms (unless these two are regular and normal, respectively). I think that identifying these simple topologies would better clarify the meaning of each, though. Thoughts?

[Here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~gauld/750-05/section2.pdf) is a quick link to the separation axioms for ease.

Comment: My only thought about this is that if you find that working out these examples is helpful, you should do it.

Comment: I don't know how to show it completely. I meant to comment right after posting, but got caught up. @Rustyn So, we know that 1 through 4 are not $T_{0}$. 5 through 9 are $T_{0}$. 1 isn't any of them, correct?

Answer (score 1):

For example, a space is $T_0$ if for every pair of distinct points in the space, *at least one* has an open neighborhood not containing the other.   
There are three unordered pairs, $\{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}$ 
$1)$ not $T_0$ 
$2)$ not $T_0$ 
$3)$ not $T_0$ 
$4)$ not $T_0$ 
$5)$ $T_0$ $\huge !$ Why?? 
$c$ has a neighborhood that doesn't contain $a$ or $b$ $\checkmark$,
$b$ has a neighborhood that doesn't contain $a$ $\checkmark$ $T_0$-ness is satisfied!

Just apply definitions, and see what you can come up with.

Comment: $T_{3} \rightarrow T_{2}$ and $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$ only hold if $T_{3}$ and $T_{4}$ are regular and normal (i.e. that $T_{2}$ is also true), correct?

Comment: Also, my book explicitly says that $T_{2}$ does not imply $T_{1}$ or $T_{0}$. I don't mean to be contradictory, but could you explain your reasoning please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint that covers some cases:

If you can find two elements that are not [topologically distinguishable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_distinguishability) in the sense that no open set exists containing exactly one of them then (even) $T_0$ is not true.

Example: in 4) $\left\{ a,b\right\} \subseteq O\vee\left\{ a,b\right\} \cap O=\emptyset$
is true for any open set $O$.

Comment: So, in 2, 3 and 4, points a and b are topologically indistinguishable. Does this imply that, for each of these topologies, none of the separation axioms hold? Or, am I inappropriately extrapolating?

Comment: Yes, that implies indeed than none of the separation axioms holds. That is also the case in 1 (you did not mention).

Comment: Ah, you're right. And, none of these should ever hold for the trivial case.

Comment: Could $T_{3}$ or $T_{4}$ (excluding $T_{0}$ through $T_{2}$) hold for 2 through 4?

Comment: You have $T_{i+1}\Rightarrow T_i$ in general for $i=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Yes, for the regular and normal cases only. $T_{4}$ need not necessarily imply $T_{3}$, which need not necessarily imply $T_{2}$. But, $T_{2}$ implies $T_{1}$ and $T_{0}$ in all cases. Consider the definition:

Comment: A space $X, \tau$ is said to be $T_{3}$ if given any closed subset F of X and any point x of X which is not in F, there are open sets U and V s.t. $x \in U, F \subset V$, and $U \cup V = \emptyset$. A space $X, \tau$ is said to be regular if X is both $T_{3}$ and $T_{2}$. I think that the issue is is that we are working with different definitions.

Comment: In the link that you gave yourself I read under definition 2.8: 'Every $T_{3}$-space is $T_{2}$'. And under definition 2.12: 'Every $T_{4}$-space is clearly a $T_{3}$-space'.

Comment: Yes, but that is specifically assuming that they are regular and normal.

Comment: It is just a fact that $T_{i+1}\Rightarrow T_i$ for $i=0,1,2,3$. This without any specifical assumptions. Also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom. We must close this discussion now.

Answer (score 0):

Following your link, you use the standard definitions, where each $T$-axiom implies the lower one.

For a finite space $T_1$ means discrete (as then all finite, hence *all*, subsets are closed), and only 9. is discrete, so $T_1$-$T_4$.

So 1-8 are not $T_1$ or higher, being non-discrete.

So decide $T_0$-ness for 1-8. Regular and normal are indeed more case to case:
 e.g. the indiscrete space 1. is trivially regular and normal, as there are no disjoint closed sets to separate at all (so logic says we can separate *all* such pairs by open sets ...), nor is there a pair $x, F$ with $F$ closed non-empty and $x \notin F$.

E.g. for 2., as $\{c\}$ is open, $\{a,b\}$ is closed, and it's the only non-trivial closed set. So normality is already trivial. But we cannot separate $c$ from $\{a,b\}$ by disjoint open sets, because the only open set that contains $\{a, b\}$ is the whole space. So space 2. is not regular, but is normal. It's *not* $T_0$ because every open set that contains $a$ also contains $b$ and vice versa.

Now you look at the others.